# WMI get certification authorities list

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmi, wmic

I try to write 2 **WMIC** commands for generate list of all installed **applications** on mashine and another one all **certificates** and write it to file.

A problem is that my certificate command does not work properly. the second command returns the same file with installed aplications apart installed certificates. and I really don't understand why, because in my opinion command looks good. This is the following 2 commands:

```
rem command to check installed aplications
wmic product get /format:csv > %USERPROFILE%/Desktop/vistadraft-applications-%Computername%-%Username%.csv && echo [.] [STARTING] && echo [.] application version list [PROCESSING] && echo [.] [FINISHED]

rem command to check installed certificates
wmic product get /format:csv > %USERPROFILE%/Desktop/vistadraft-certificates-%Computername%-%Username%.csv && echo [.] [STARTING] && echo [.] certification authorities list [PROCESSING] && echo [.] [FINISHED]
```

Please, maybe whom know where is a problem?

Comment: ok what does _"don't work well"_ mean? what happens, what error you receive etc. will help us understand the problem you have better than just _It does not work_

Comment: don't work well it means generate same file with all application as the first command does

Comment: the error is that command generates just empty list

Comment: ok, save the batchfile somewhere easily accessible, then right click on it and select `Run as Administrator`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard oh , thanks , now i get an error , that is invalid command --------------------------------------------------------- wmic product get /format:csv > %USERPROFILE%/Desktop/vistadraft-certificates-%Computername%-%Username%.csv && echo [.] [STARTING] && echo [.] certification authorities list [PROCESSING] && echo [.] [FINISHED]

Comment: edit your question and post the exact error please.

Comment: updated, now second command returns the same list with applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826699(v=vs.85).aspx)

> To run the following WMI Command-Line Tools, your account must be in the Administrators group and the tool must be run from an elevated command prompt. The built-in administrator account can also run these tools.

Therefore you need to run wmic as an administrator.

**a.** Simply right click on `cmd.exe` and select `"Run as Administrator"` then run your script from there.

**or**

**b.** save the batch file and right click, selecting `Run as Administrator`

Lastly, I suggest you wrap your path in double quotes.

```
rem command to check installed aplications
wmic product get /format:csv > "%USERPROFILE%/Desktop/vistadraft-applications-%Computername%-%Username%.csv" && echo [.] [STARTING] && echo [.] application version list [PROCESSING] && echo [.] [FINISHED]

rem command to check installed certificates
wmic product get /format:csv > "%USERPROFILE%/Desktop/vistadraft-certificates-%Computername%-%Username%.csv" && echo [.] [STARTING] && echo [.] certification authorities list [PROCESSING] && echo [.] [FINISHED]
```

Comment: @oh thanks Gerhard again , look , i got an error: Invalid XSL format (or) file name. , i try to replace /format:"%WINDIR%\System32\wbem\en-US\csv"        instead of /format:csv because my windows 7 , and it not helps

Comment: yes , it still same , hmm , Gerhard , maybe you know how can i get the **certification authorities list** and write it to file? maybe are present same ways to get it ? and it possible to get it ?

Comment: Did you copy the code in my answer exactly and tried?

Comment: Cool, no problem.

Comment: maybe you know how to get certification authorities list ?

Comment: not sure exactly what you want, but try `powershell Get-ChildItem -Recurse Cert:` from batch